# Trying to run Second Life but it's giving an error even though I have the latest drivers. What's wrong?

Tags: technical-issues, graphics-card, second-life

> Unable to run because your video card drivers did not install properly, are out of date, or are for unsupported hardware. Please make sure you have the latest video card drivers and even if you do have the latest, try reinstalling them.

I've downloaded the utility application "PC Pitstop Driver Alert2" that reports no updates for my driver. It says the video card driver is already up to date... the driver name listed in Display Adapters is this:

**Intel(R) 82945G Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.0)**

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate Operating System. Why am I not able to run the game?

Second Life used to run perfectly when I had Windows XP pro installed in my PC..Now I have switched to Windows 7 Ultimate and been having this problem ever since..I am just not able to run it!..If the drivers are up to date..what's the problem then ?

Comment: It would help if you will actually specify what game you are trying to run. Also, I recommend checking the game's system requirements in advance to verify it can run on that chipset and doesn't require a discrete graphics card.

Comment: @Oak::have added details

Comment: No WDDM 1.1 driver?  For shame Intel, for shame... WDDM 1.1 reduces the amount of RAM needed per-process for display rendering.

Comment: Have you tried running your game in Windows XP compatibility mode? It's possible that the problem is Windows 7 in general, rather than your graphics drivers, specifically.

Comment: @Everyone: He mentioned in a previous edit that **The game in question is SecondLife**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that "Pitstop" application. In any case, you can download the latest drivers for your device directly from Intel's site - here are direct links, choose according to your edition of Windows:

- [For Windows 7 Ultimate **32-bit**](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18223&ProdId=2102&lang=eng)
- [For Windows 7 Ultimate **64-bit**](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18228&ProdId=2102&lang=eng)

Comment: cool..thanks..I ll just try n d/l the driver..hope the problem goes away

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like one of those "your computer may not be up to date! download this now!1!" malware apps

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](https://jira.secondlife.com/browse/VWR-11527?), running the game with the `--noprobe` command-line option will cause it to start without the video card check.

*(you can add command-line options to shortcuts by right-clicking the shortcut, going to properties, and appending the option to the end of the "target" box)*

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a question to ask specifically on the forum (or other support site) for the game in question. Many games have very disparate white-lists and black-lists for which combinations of video card, driver version, and operating system it will allow to play. Because these vary from game to game, but all produce similarly useless error messages akin to the one you have discovered here, the community of that specific game and/or its support staff may have a better idea of why your configuration is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Intel has a page [here](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/intel945g/sb/CS-020666.htm) that lists games that will work on your graphics chip:

> Intel has compiled a list of popular games that are playable on the Intel® 82945G Express Chipset on Microsoft Windows* XP. This information is provided solely as a convenience for customers. The list is not intended to be complete or all-inclusive, and is subject to change or revision without notice.

As you haven't specified the game I can't check whether it's listed or not.